# JSTL c:url tag - servlet context

Tags: jsp, url, jstl

We are writing application that uses Spring MVC. Today I had little fun wit `c:url` tag in .jsp files.

So I fought that finally it is the time to know what excatly this tag do.

For example on this page: http://heavyz.sourceforge.net/homepage/homepage_zh/comp/notes/jstl-core.html I can read that it does something like this

> Prepending the name of the current servlet context

and

> The value attribute is used to specify a base URL, which the tag then
>   transforms as necessary.  If this base URL starts with a forward
>   slash, then a servlet context name will be prepended. An explicit
>   context name can be provided using the context attribute.  If this
>   attribute is omitted, then the name of the current servlet context
>   will be used.

but I am wondering about this `current servlet context` thing, because I have in my login form

```
    <form name='f' action="<c:url value='/j_spring_security_check' />"
    method='POST'>
    <fieldset>

        <div class="form_elem">
            <label for="j_username">Login: </label> <input type="text"
                name="j_username" value="" />
        </div>
        <div class="form_elem">
            <label for="j_password" accesskey="l">Hasło:</label> <input
                type="password" name="j_password">
        </div>
        <div class="form_elem">
            <label for="_spring_security_remember_me">Zapamiętaj mnie?</label> <input
                type='checkbox' name='_spring_security_remember_me'
                id="_spring_security_remember_me" value="true" />
        </div>
        <input name="submit" type="submit" value="Send" class="newline" />
    </fieldset>
    <a href="register">Register</a><br>
</form>
```

you can notice the slash near `j_spring_security_check`, but before I didn't have this slash, and when someone refreshed after registration he got login page rendered but this link in the browser for example

```
localhost:8080/taboret/activateAccount/50555449564956495757565057535150535649494956565550554949565752545053505252485450
```

If now the login form was sent, it got sent to the `http://localhost:8080/taboret/activateAccount/j_spring_security_check`

but I was thinking that this servlet context would be just the `taboret`, the name of the application.

What this `Prepending the name of the current servlet context` mean then?

Comment: There are 2 contexts.  ContextPath (this is the place the whole WAR is deployed) and the ServletPath this is the path prefix of the servlet being used (I guess for you this will be the spring MVC Dispatch Servlet as configed in web.xml).  I presume you are using "spring-security" and usually it has a filter in place for "**/j_spring_security_check" which means it does not matter how many path segments are before it; it should still work.

Comment: That is the thing, in the situation I described and without the slash it didn't work. I am getting the `405 error, POST not supported in the situation I described`

Comment: This will be a config matter and if you remove the <c:url ..> use and the leading slash, you get the same URL being hit and the same PORT method not supported.  The method not supported is a config matter.